# How can I optimize the following query in laravel eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I am trying to fetch some result from a table in a particular order.

I have a table, with few thousands questions. Each question have a category_id.

My task is, collect 100 questions from this table, in random order. Where first 30 questions will be from category_id =1, next 30 questions from category_id =2, and last 40 question from category_id=3.

My current solution is:

```
Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id',1)->limit(30)->get()

Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id',2)->limit(30)->get()                  

Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id',3)->limit(40)->get()
```

My question is, can I get same result with only one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With unions you could do the following.

```
$questions = Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id',1)->limit(30)
->union(Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id',2)->limit(30))
->union(Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id',3)->limit(40))
->get();
```

Technically a single query, but I'd rather have 3 queries.

Comment: I don't think so. Making `category_id` an index if it's not already (foreign key counts as an index) is the only optimization (as far as SQL queries go) I feel you can get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [union](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#unions)

```php
$q1 = Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id', 1)->limit(30);

$q2 = Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id', 2)->limit(30);

$value = Question::inRandomOrder()->where('category_id', 3)->limit(40)->union($q1)->union($q2)->get();
```